# Excel 2010 VBA Check for Part of a file path

Tags: excel, vba

Hi I am trying to create a code that checks for part of a file name and then will save the document with a increment of that file name, for example the below is creating a file name then using left to get just the part I want to check if it exists in any form but how do I check if a filename contains that info

```
TicketNumber = "0"
FileE = 1
UName = Range("C1")

On Error GoTo ErrorDocumentName
With New FileSystemObject
    Do While FileE = 1
        FileName = "REM" & TicketNumber & " - " & UName & ".xlsm"
        Pos = InStr(FileName, "-")
        LeftFN = Left(FileName, Pos - 2)
        LeftFP = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & LeftFN
        FileP = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & FileName
        DisplayName = "REM" & TicketNumber
            If .FileExists(LeftFP & WildC) Then
                TicketNumber = TicketNumber + 1
            ElseIf Not .FileExists(LeftFP & WildC) Then
                FileE = 0
            End If
    Loop
End With

On Error GoTo ErrorRunning

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FileName:=FileP, FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False
ActiveSheet.Name = "Incident"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub
```

Comment: Where should that file be located which you want to check for filename? In a specific folder? If so you should loop through all the files in that folder, to search for a match.

Comment: edit it into your original post